# How to create multi controls Flexslider?

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I am looking for a solution to have multiple `manualControls`. To be clear, two manualControls.

The idea behind this is that I can switch between an manualControl for desktop and mobile, because the position in the markup is for the mobile on another place, than on desktop. If there is another solution to get the manualControls div to another place on resize let me know!

I use this markup:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    controlsContainer: ".flexslider",
    manualControls: ".custom-controls li",
    customDirectionNav: ".custom-direction li a",
    useCSS: false, /* Chrome fix*/
    slideshow: false,
    start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

I tried this one:

```
function flexslider() {
        if (!isMobile) {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                slideshowSpeed: 5000,
                controlsContainer: ".flexslider",
                manualControls: ".custom-controls li",
                customDirectionNav: ".custom-direction li a",
                useCSS: false, /* Chrome fix*/
                slideshow: false,
                start: function(slider){
                    $('body').removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        } 
        if (isMobile) {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                slideshowSpeed: 5000,
                controlsContainer: ".flexslider",
                manualControls: ".mobile-controls li",
                customDirectionNav: ".custom-direction li a",
                useCSS: false, /* Chrome fix*/
                slideshow: false,
                start: function(slider){
                    $('body').removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        }
    } 
    setInterval(function(){ flexslider(); }, 3000);

function resizer() {
    var w = $(window).width();

    if (w <= 768) {
        isMobile = true;
        console.log('isMobile');
    } else {
        isMobile = false;
        console.log('!isMobile');
    }
```

flexslider();

```
} resizer();


$( window ).resize(function () { 
    resizer();
});
```

Above script will only work on refreshing the page, not on resize.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if you can do that since the flexslider has initialized. But you could use `flexAnimate(id)` method to jump to the slide you want.

For example `$('.flexslider').data('flexslider').flexAnimate(2)` will go to the third slide (the first one is the `0`).